# Can't parse JSON response via @POST Request with parameters using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, rest, kotlin, retrofit

So i'm trying to handle and print a JSON response to my server and I'm getting the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY
>   at line 1 column 1376 path $.scope

Here what my project looks like:

object RetrofitClientInstance {

```
private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
private val BASE_URL = "http://security-xxx.xxx.xxx.corp"

//create a retrofit instance, only if its not created yet
val retrofitInstance: Retrofit?
    get() {

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit
    }
```

}

interface GetApiService {

```
@GET("/xxx/token")
fun getToken(@Header("Authorization") token: String): Call<TokenResponse>

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/oauth/token")
fun requestTokenFromEP(
    @Field("client_id") clientId: String,
    @Field("client_secret") clientSecret: String,
    @Field("grant_type") grantType: String,
    @Field("username") username: String,
    @Field("password") password: String,
    @Field("role") role: String
) : Call<TokenResponse>
```

This is My DTO class

```
data class TokenResponse(
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    var accessToken: String,
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    var tokenType: String,
    @SerializedName("refresh_token")
    var refreshToken: String,
    @SerializedName("scope")
    var scope: String
)
```

My Activity

```
private fun doTokenRequest(){
    //get service
    val service = RetrofitClientInstance.retrofitInstance?.create(GetApiService::class.java)
    //do call
    val call = service?.requestTokenFromEP(TokenUtils.clientId, TokenUtils.clientSecret, TokenUtils.grantType,TokenUtils.username, TokenUtils.password, TokenUtils.role)
    //process it
    call?.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<TokenResponse>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<TokenResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            println("failed: " + t.message)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<TokenResponse>, response: Response<TokenResponse>) {
            println("success")
            var myList: TokenResponse = response.body()!!
            println(myList.toString())
        }

    })

}
```

JSON Expected Response

```
{
    "access_token": "xxxxx",
    "token_type": "xxxxx",
    "refresh_token": "xxxxxxx",
    "expires_in": 553,
    "scope": "read"
}
```

Please guys if you can help me I would like to understand

Comment: **Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 1376 path $.scope** this error means "The response you are getting from the server is not matching with your model class as it is saying it is expecting String but it got a Array. So recheck your model class and Server Response. Or post a snippet of your server response.

Comment: yes you were right! in my model class the scope parametre was of type string but my JSON was returning a List in that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I already figure out the answer:

In my model class the "scope" variable was of type string but my JSON was returning an Array, hence why the app was returning an error.

The JSON response returned: 
"scope": [
       "read",
       "write"]

Comment: edit your question and say **Solved! Answer Below** something like that